# Upload large file using SOAP web service

Tags: android, web-services, file-upload, out-of-memory, android-ksoap2

I need  to upload a file which is vary from 10-100mb.  When I try to upload the file, it gives me outofmemory error in line

```
sb.append(Base64.encode(data));
```

How can I solve this issue? My web service is SOAP webservice. Here is the complete code of the method.

```
 public static String fileToBase64(String path) throws IOException {
            File imagefile = new File(path);
            byte[] data = new byte[3000];
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
                while(fin.read(data) >= 0) {
                   sb.append(Base64.encode(data));
               }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally{
                fin.close();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two methods:

1. Use streamed XML writer and chunked content to avoid excessive memory consumption. Not sure if it is applicable here.
2. Use [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism) to send SOAP messages with attachments.

This method is preferable, but you must add required functionality to your webservice.